# "Learning" paths in a binary tree

Tags: probability, combinatorics, trees, random

Let $T$ be a complete binary tree with $2^n$ leaves and let $I$ be a random variable on $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ that outputs $i$ with probability $p_i$ for each $i=0,...,n-1$.

Two nodes are *siblings* if and only if they share a parent. The sibling of a node's parent is called that node's *1-uncle*; the sibling of its grandparent is that node's *2-uncle*; the sibling of its great-grandparent is its *3-uncle*, and so on. For a given leaf node $l$, the *uncle set* of $l$ consists of all its $i$-uncles for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$.

Now, consider the following experiment: In each round, toss an unbiased $2^n$-sided die to get a leaf index $l$ and sample an $i\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ using $I$. Mark both the $l$th leaf and (if $i>0$) that leaf's $i$-uncle as "known". Finally, mark any node for which both children are "known" as being "known" (recursively until no new nodes become "known").

Fix $k\in\{1,\ldots,2^n\}$. What is the expected number of rounds before the $k$th leaf and every element of its uncle set are "known"?

(I am also interested in the answer in the case where we mark every uncle from the $1$-uncle up to the $i$-uncle as "known" in each round.)

Comment: What do you mean by "number of rounds before the $k$th leaf and its entire uncle set is known?" What is $k$? If you just want to "know" one specified leaf $k$ and its uncle set, then by symmetry it doesn't matter which leaf you specify. Or are you looking for the first time that there are $k$ different leaves such that they and their uncle sets are all known?

Comment: What does "the entire uncle set" mean?  Please [edit] the question to clarify the problem statement.  Don't put clarifications in the comments -- instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and will be useful to others in the future.